# C# Windows 10, SetDeviceGammaRamp doesn't work with multiple monitors and/or an Nvidia card? Too many posts made to a semaphore

Tags: c#, windows, dllimport, gamma

Trying to control monitor gamma using C# using DLLImport to run **SetDeviceGammaRamp** in gdi32.dll. Similar to the answer on this question which controls brightness similarly: [SetDeviceGammaRamp just blinks the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171027/setdevicegammaramp-just-blinks-the-screen) .

The problem is, SetDeviceGammaRamp never works on my main workstation, which has an Nvidia GTX 1070 video card and 3 monitors attached to it. It always returns false, initially with the error **"Too many posts were made to a semaphore."** After that error, it continues to return false and not work but with error code 0 ("Operation completed successfully"). It's a Windows Forms app if that matters. I also tried a console version, and it also but failed but not with the semaphore error, just with the "completed successfully" error.

Interestingly enough, if I run the exact same application on a PC without a video card and only with a single monitor, the code works! However after running the function multiple times, it will eventually stop working with the same semaphore error on that machine too, until re-running the application, but at least I know SetDeviceGammaRamp *can* still work.

I'm completely at a loss at how to solve the error, or why it won't work at all on my main workstation. Is it because I have a video card and am not using onboard graphics? Is it because I have multiple monitors? I've tried trying to specify specific monitor DC's using similar code to this ([How to change the gamma ramp of a single display monitor (NVidia Config)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486842/how-to-change-the-gamma-ramp-of-a-single-display-monitor-nvidia-config)), but the results on my main workstation are always exactly the same.

Last note - it also only works when compiled. If run the app through Visual Studio (debug or release), it fails with a different error "The resource loader failed to find MUI file", but maybe this may be normal with accessing system DLL's this way?

Comment: It is a fickle function, Google provides lots of hits.  Beyond the universal trouble with expecting display drivers to do something unusual, and something their shovelware is expected to do, I suspect that anti-malware is involved.  It is ideal to implement malware with a single innocent-looking api call.  Learning how to adjust your monitor brightness is the far simpler way.

Comment: Dang. So I'm probably out of luck finding any relatively simple way to automate gamma change? The information is much appreciated, I suppose I can live without it (but I'm happy to go on a wild goose chase hunting down any leads if you have any more!).

Comment: @bk999 Hey, I can confirm I see exactly the same behavior. When a single monitor is connected to an Nvidia graphics card, it works. Multiple displays, it doesn't. Have you found a solution. If not, I'd normally say it's a bug in Nvidia drivers, but Google says AMD GPUs have the same issue. So sounds like a Windows bugs to me...

Comment: @deLock  Never found a solution for this unfortunately, just was able to recreate it as described on various machines.

Comment: It's a bug that should be reported to Microsoft. Or possibly to both AMD and Nvidia. It must be their bug.